# I cannot figure it out if i have a problem or not

Tags: networking, dnsmasq

I am having an ASUS router, and in the logs in the last couple of days i get a lot of :

```
Jul 19 21:00:32 dnsmasq-dhcp[389]: DHCPACK(br0) 192.168.1.15 84:a6:c8:6a:6a:4e HELLiPOD-PC
Jul 19 21:00:37 dnsmasq-dhcp[389]: DHCPINFORM(br0) 192.168.1.15 84:a6:c8:6a:6a:4e 
Jul 19 21:00:37 dnsmasq-dhcp[389]: DHCPACK(br0) 192.168.1.15 84:a6:c8:6a:6a:4e HELLiPOD-PC
Jul 19 21:00:40 kernel: DROP IN=eth3 OUT= MAC=10:bf:48:3d:a9:c3:00:07:0d:72:d0:00:08:00 SRC=216.52.1.12 DST=188.214.245.134 LEN=71 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=57 ID=7916 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=60744 SEQ=3996761440 ACK=2533517677 WINDOW=31 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Jul 19 21:00:52 kernel: DROP IN=eth3 OUT= MAC=10:bf:48:3d:a9:c3:00:07:0d:72:d0:00:08:00 SRC=31.5.51.93 DST=188.214.245.134 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=122 ID=16050 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=62106 DPT=62267 SEQ=3752754106 ACK=0 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40103030201010402) 
Jul 19 21:00:55 kernel: DROP IN=eth3 OUT= MAC=10:bf:48:3d:a9:c3:00:07:0d:72:d0:00:08:00 SRC=31.5.51.93 DST=188.214.245.134 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=122 ID=17158 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=62106 DPT=62267 SEQ=3752754106 ACK=0 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40103030201010402) 
Jul 19 21:00:56 dnsmasq-dhcp[389]: DHCPREQUEST(br0) 192.168.1.16 bc:5f:f4:4a:a1:13 
Jul 19 21:00:56 dnsmasq-dhcp[389]: DHCPACK(br0) 192.168.1.16 bc:5f:f4:4a:a1:13 DESKTOP-UP1LOMR
Jul 19 21:01:01 kernel: DROP IN=eth3 OUT= MAC=10:bf:48:3d:a9:c3:00:07:0d:72:d0:00:08:00 SRC=31.5.51.93 DST=188.214.245.134 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=122 ID=19799 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=62106 DPT=62267 SEQ=3752754106 ACK=0 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B401010402) 
Jul 19 21:01:23 dnsmasq-dhcp[389]: DHCPREQUEST(br0) 192.168.1.18 04:e6:76:90:5b:f9 
Jul 19 21:01:23 dnsmasq-dhcp[389]: DHCPACK(br0) 192.168.1.18 04:e6:76:90:5b:f9 Corina
Jul 19 21:01:26 dnsmasq-dhcp[389]: DHCPREQUEST(br0) 192.168.1.15 84:a6:c8:6a:6a:4e 
Jul 19 21:01:26 dnsmasq-dhcp[389]: DHCPACK(br0) 192.168.1.15 84:a6:c8:6a:6a:4e HELLiPOD-PC
Jul 19 21:01:49 dnsmasq-dhcp[389]: DHCPREQUEST(br0) 192.168.1.16 bc:5f:f4:4a:a1:13 
Jul 19 21:01:49 dnsmasq-dhcp[389]: DHCPACK(br0) 192.168.1.16 bc:5f:f4:4a:a1:13 DESKTOP-UP1LOMR
Jul 19 21:02:06 kernel: DROP IN=eth3 OUT= MAC=10:bf:48:3d:a9:c3:00:07:0d:72:d0:00:08:00 SRC=31.131.44.156 DST=188.214.245.134 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=120 ID=16047 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=61429 DPT=62267 SEQ=3838155013 ACK=0 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40103030801010402) 
Jul 19 21:02:09 kernel: DROP IN=eth3 OUT= MAC=10:bf:48:3d:a9:c3:00:07:0d:72:d0:00:08:00 SRC=31.131.44.156 DST=188.214.245.134 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=120 ID=18101 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=61429 DPT=62267 SEQ=3838155013 ACK=0 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40103030801010402) 
Jul 19 21:02:15 kernel: DROP IN=eth3 OUT= MAC=10:bf:48:3d:a9:c3:00:07:0d:72:d0:00:08:00 SRC=31.131.44.156 DST=188.214.245.134 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=120 ID=24557 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=61429 DPT=62267 SEQ=3838155013 ACK=0 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B401010402) 


Jul 19 21:02:19 dnsmasq-dhcp[389]: DHCPREQUEST(br0) 192.168.1.15 84:a6:c8:6a:6a:4e 
Jul 19 21:02:19 dnsmasq-dhcp[389]: DHCPACK(br0) 192.168.1.15 84:a6:c8:6a:6a:4e HELLiPOD-PC
Jul 19 21:02:29 dnsmasq-dhcp[389]: DHCPREQUEST(br0) 192.168.1.18 04:e6:76:90:5b:f9 
Jul 19 21:02:29 dnsmasq-dhcp[389]: DHCPACK(br0) 192.168.1.18 04:e6:76:90:5b:f9 Corina
Jul 19 21:02:45 dnsmasq-dhcp[389]: DHCPREQUEST(br0) 192.168.1.16 bc:5f:f4:4a:a1:13 
Jul 19 21:02:45 dnsmasq-dhcp[389]: DHCPACK(br0) 192.168.1.16 bc:5f:f4:4a:a1:13 DESKTOP-UP1LOMR
Jul 19 21:02:46 kernel: DROP IN=eth3 OUT=MAC=10:bf:48:3d:a9:c3: 00:07:0d:72:d0:00:08:00 SRC=79.113.65.94 DST=188.214.245.134 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=120 ID=23740 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51983 DPT=62267 SEQ=1957489607 ACK=0 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405A00103030801010402) 
Jul 19 21:02:49 kernel: DROP IN=eth3 OUT= MAC=10:bf:48:3d:a9:c3:00:07:0d:72:d0:00:08:00 SRC=79.113.65.94 DST=188.214.245.134 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=120 ID=23752 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51983 DPT=62267 SEQ=1957489607 ACK=0 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405A00103030801010402) 
Jul 19 21:02:55 kernel: DROP IN=eth3 OUT= MAC=10:bf:48:3d:a9:c3:00:07:0d:72:d0:00:08:00 SRC=79.113.65.94 DST=188.214.245.134 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=120 ID=23762 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51983 DPT=62267 SEQ=1957489607 ACK=0 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405A001010402)
```

Comment: Have you noticed any actual problems with your connection, or are you just concerned about the log files?

Answer (score 0):

No, it just looks like your `DESKTOP-UP1LOMR` and `Corina` and `HELLiPOD-PC` are renewing their IP address , that's all. IP addresses are not permanent and expire on local network over time, so they need to request that IP is renewed

Answer (score 0):

As Serg said, devices "Handshake" with their internet providing source (Modem, Switch, Router, etc.) many times per (time period selected/defined by the Modem, Router, Switch and/or other connection providing device) minute (this, in order to retain their IP address and connection to that source).  This is common for all networked devices. If your connection remains active and functional there is no cause for concern at all.